# Kubuntu 16.04 hybrid amd graphics card blank window

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, 16.04, hybrid-graphics, amd-graphics

I am on a laptop with Intel/AMD hybrid GPU, and I believe I have the driver AMDGPU enabled by default. `xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink` was also set to the AMD card.

So I tried to launch steam with `DRI_PRIME=1` to utilize the discrete card but nothing comes up. It works perfectly fine if the `DRI_PRIME` option is not set. 
I also did some tests using `glxgears`. I only get a black window with no image/animation with `DRI_PRIME=1`.
What could be the issue? Thanks in advance

Edit: it seems to be a compositor problem. It shows up if I do the following:

- disable/enable compositor
- minimizing/maximizing the window
- resizing the window

Comment: This needs more information:

`xrandr --listproviders` to know which devices we are talking about. Even a `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|Display` will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is related or not, but 16.04 (all flavors) drops a lot of support for AMD cards.

"There’s good and bad news for AMD graphics users. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS will support AMD’s new AMDGPU graphics driver architecture, which should help close the gap with Nvidia’s exceptional Linux drivers. Unfortunately, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS no longer supports the current AMD Catalyst driver, also known as “fglrx.” AMD graphics card users may want to stick with Ubuntu 14.04 until AMDGPU has matured. That is, if you’re using the card for gaming or other demanding chores. AMD graphics will work just fine if you’re performing standard desktop activities."

I see you're using AMDGPU--this could be part of the "immaturity" this quote refers to....

http://www.pcworld.com/article/3058857/linux/ubuntu-1604-lts-gives-fans-new-reasons-to-love-this-popular-linux-desktop.html